# How to style a blockquote with large curly braces around it

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style a block of text so that it is surrounded by a large curly brace on each side (so that each brace takes up the whole height of each side of the element). Here is the HTML:

```
<blockquote>
<span class="braceleft">&#123;</span>
<p class="quotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus           Pellentesque at neque lorem, vitae aliquet risus.</p>
<span class="braceright">&#125;</span></blockquote>
```

I should also mention that I am trying to do this in WordPress, which I know can add unwanted tags. If I could get the right CSS for plain HTML, I can hopefully figure out how to strip the unwanted tags.

I can easily change the HTML markup if that would make styling easier.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the <span> and <p> tags. Edit the opening <blockquote> tag to 
<blockquote class="addCurlys">. Use this CSS (play with the font-size for the :before and :after pseudoelements):

```
blockquote  {
    font-size:1em;
}
blockquote.addCurlys:before {
    content: "{";
    font-size:10em;
}
blockquote.addCurlys:after {
    content: "}";
    font-size:10em;
}
```

Because em is the unit of measurement for the :before and :after pseudoelements, they're linked to the font-size of their parent - the blockquote itself.

I think most browsers now support :: for pseudoelements - I still tend to only use one

Comment: Because your adding the `{` and `}` from CSS shouldn't the `<span>` tags in his markup be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you should restrict content to make it fit inside curly brackets.

You can probably do something like

```
<blockquote class="clearfix">
  <div class="curly-left float-left">
    <div class="float-left"> Content here </div>
  <div class="curly-right float-left">
</blockquote>
```

Then in the CSS you set the hight / width and background image for curly left and right. 
Float the divs and use clearfix on the `blockquote`.

I think that should do it.

Here's the code I use for clearfix

```
/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="braceleft" style="float:left; padding: 0 10px">&#123;</span>
<p class="quotation" style="float:left; padding: 0; margin: 0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus Pellentesque at neque lorem, vitae aliquet risus.</p>
<span class="braceright" style="float:left; padding: 0 10px">&#125;</span>
```

Comment: When I styled it the way you suggest, I get a normal-sized brace, the quotation on the next line, and another normal-sized brace on the next line. I want the braces to be on either side of the quotation and take up the entire height of the quotation block.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it without additional tags would be to use CSS's `:before` and `:after` to create the 2 braces and then style them accordingly.

Consider this code (or [test the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/BpgX6/6/)):

HTML:

```
<blockquote class="addCurlys">I like curly <br> curls <br/><br/> I really do<br/><br/>I really really do</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
BLOCKQUOTE.addCurlys {background: yellow; position: relative; padding: 0.5ex; 1em}
BLOCKQUOTE.addCurlys:before {
    content: ''; border: 1px dotted pink;
    position: absolute; right: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 30px; 
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/30/60'); background-size: 100% 100%
}
BLOCKQUOTE.addCurlys:after {
    content: ''; border: 1px dotted pink;
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 30px;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/30/60'); background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

Here's how it works (for the opening brace): `:before` creates a pseudo-element. We need to add the `content` attribute otherwise it won't be rendered 'properly'. The pink border is only there so you can see where it is.

The `BLOCKQUOTE` is given a `position: relative` attribute so that the before and after blocks can be positioned relative to it. We give `:before` a `position: absolute` and give it a `top` and `bottom` value of 0 so that it gets aligned with the blockquote's top and bottom edges. Then we give it a `right: 100%` so that it gets pushed all the way to the left of the edge (could use `left:0` if you want it inside the blockquote, adjust for your tastes). And a `width` to our liking.

Finally we add a background (since you wanted the curl to stretch vertically) image and specify that we want it to be sized 100% by 100% of the container (`:before`, i.e. the opening brace). Feel free to change the kitten images to curly braces, I prefer kittens.

Adjust for your needs.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with typography and not with images?

Comment: It's possible to set the `content` to something like `content: '{'`, but I'm not sure how to stretch it so that it takes the entire height of the `BLOCKQUOTE`